# Fake proof of one-to-one function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, fake-proofs

Prove or disprove that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is one-to-one if,

$$f(x) = -3x^2+7$$

Assume $f(x) = f(y)$, then

$$-3x^2+7 = -3y^2+7$$

$$-3x^2 = -3y^2$$

$$x^2 = y^2$$

$$x = y$$

Hence function is one-to-one.

While we can easily see that function is not one-to-one. For example $f(-1)=f(1)$.

Where is the proof wrong?

Comment: This is said in the answers, I just want to make it absolutely clear: $x^2 = y^2$ does not imply that $x=y$. You can see this by your own example $(-1)^2=1^2$, but $-1\neq 1$.

Comment: And what about $x^3=y^3$? Does that imply x=y?

Comment: @user3834119, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x^3 = y^3 \Leftrightarrow x = y$.

Comment: @user3834119 Yes, as long as $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. The problem is when you have an even exponent since that makes a negative number positive.

Comment: An `even` function can't be one-to-one.

Comment: Over the real field yes. One way to see it:
$x^3-y^3 = x^3(1-(\frac{y}{x})^3) = x^3(1-\frac{y}{x})(1+\frac{y}{x}+(\frac{y}{x})^2)$ ; $x^3 = y^3$ <=> $x=y$ or $1+\frac{y}{x}+(\frac{y}{x})^2 = 0$ But $x^3=y^3 \implies$ x and y of the same sign $\implies u=\frac{y}{x}>0 \implies 1+u+u^2 >0 \implies x=y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is wrong because $$x^2=y^2\iff x=\pm y$$
and not just $x=y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2 = y^2 \Leftrightarrow x = \pm y$$